# How to run http-kit using boot?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring, http-kit, boot-clj

I am not able to get any response from the http-kit server when running using boot. It works with jetty. When I run the `boot run` the it exits after sometime. So I added `(boot (wait))` which doesn't terminate, but the server seems to be not running.

```
; core.clj
(ns server.core
    (:use [compojure.route :only [files not-found]]
          [compojure.handler :only [site]]
          [compojure.core :only [defroutes GET POST DELETE ANY context]]
          org.httpkit.server))

(defn hello [] 
    "Hello from httpkit")

(defroutes api-routes
    (GET "/" [] (hello)))

(defn -main []
    (run-server api-routes {:port 8080}))
```

The `boot.clj` file:

```
;boot.clj
(set-env!
    :source-paths #{"src"}
    :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                    [ring "1.5.0"]
                    [compojure "1.5.1"]
                    [http-kit "2.2.0"]])

(require '[server.core :as server])

(deftask run []
    (with-pre-wrap fileset (server/-main) fileset)
    (boot (wait)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boot-http](https://github.com/pandeiro/boot-http) and something like the following:

```
 (boot (serve :handler 'server/-main :reload true) (wait))
```

Comment: I used boot-http and ran it like this: `(boot (serve :handler 'server.core/-main :reload true) (wait)))`. But boot is starting jetty at 3000 and when loading the url I get `Problem accessing /. Reason: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core/-main`. It's very easy and straight forward to use lein, not sure why boot is making this difficult.